# Binding does not work with a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to change the Fill of a Rectangle depending on a boolean. I have the following classes.

**Base class that extends INotifyPropertyChanged:**

```
public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class ChangingVariable : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ChangingVariable()
    {
        Variable = true;
    }

    private bool _variable;

    public bool Variable
    {
        get
        {
            return _variable;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_variable.CompareTo(value) != 0)
            {
                _variable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class BooleanRectangleViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ChangingVariable Model { get; set; }
}
```

This is my View that does *not* work (Fill is gray):

xaml:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:BooleanRectangleViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.Variable}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="GreenYellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

cs:

```
public partial class BooleanRectangleView
{
    public BooleanRectangleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel.Model = new ChangingVariable();
    }
}
```

However when I change it such that the data context is the Model instead of the ViewModel, it works (Fill is green):

xaml:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <models:ChangingVariable x:Name="ViewModel" />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Variable}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="GreenYellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

cs:

```
public partial class BooleanRectangleView
{
    public BooleanRectangleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new ChangingVariable();
    }
}
```

Why does it not work with the ViewModel inbetween?

Comment: Your `ViewModel` in-between doesn't implement notification when you set `ViewModel.Model` value. Try to use `ViewModel.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ViewModel.Model))` after you set `ViewModel.Model` in constructor. Generally you should use full property with notification in such cases. If you would set `Model = new ChangingVariable()` in e.g. `Model` constructor, then you wouldn't notice missing notification.

Comment: Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` or not has nothing to do with this. The problem is that the binding engine could not find the source property. Without `INotifyPropertyChanged`, this would simply work as a one-time binding with the binding engine working harder to try to subscribe to the source property's changes (i.e. PropertyInfo).

Comment: @Sinatr: When I set ViewModel.Model, OnPropertyChanged will be called from inside Model. Is that not enough? What do you mean by "full property"?

Comment: @Jai: So I don't need to call OnPropertyChanged at all?

Comment: Simply do it and see if it change anything. I am not posting as an answer, because I am not 100% sure. But I see what you set value of property **after** it was used by binding engine (somewhere inside `InitializeComponents()`) and notifying should do a trick if that's the case. See for binding errors in Output window if the case is a wrong path, I never set ViewModel from xaml myself, could be a case (see @Jai answer if it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, when you do binding within a template or style, it is always better to use `RelativeSource`. I am not absolute sure, but you can try:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Model.Variable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="GreenYellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

### Update

I am also quite new to WPF/MVVM, but I would like to share something that I learnt over these short two to three months, that may help others in troubleshooting binding issues.

Whenever a binding does not work, the most likely reason is that binding engine is not able to find the binding source or the source property. Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (or using `DependencyProperty`) simply provides a way for the binding to get notified when the source property's value is changed. If you remove that part out, the binding is going to work as if it is in `OneTime` mode. The reason is simple - the binding engine is intelligent enough to know that it has to get the value from the source property in order for the target property to work.

For example, you have `<Border BorderBrush="{Binding MyBorderColor}" ....>`. When your control is about to render itself, the control **needs to know** what color the border is, otherwise it cannot proceed to render. The binding engine is forced to search for the source property `MyBorderColor`. If the binding fails, the `BorderBrush` target property will not get a value, which would result in the Border using whatever default or inherited values. If `MyBorderColor` is not implementing 'INotifyPropertyChanged' nor is it a `DependencyProperty`, then if `MyBorderColor` changes value some time during runtime, it will not be reflected in `BorderBrush`, because the binding engine is not aware that the source property has changed.

Comment: You mean I should use RelativeSource instead of `<UserControl.DataContext>` ?

Comment: @gartenriese Added some extra sharing and elaboration.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a bool to Color conversion, so I would write this class:

```
public class BooleanToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var isTrue = (bool) value;

        if (isTrue)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then suggest this converter in your XAML binding. For the full documentation on using valueconverters, look here: 
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/

Comment: Thanks, this however does not answer why my approach does not work.

Comment: The place where you're calling OnPropertyChanged, does it fire the property change event  with the name of the property? Could be that easy

Comment: Ah, no, obviously it does not! Thanks, I have to figure out how to give it the correct name.

Comment: No, that was not it, if I call `OnPropertyChanged("Model.Variable")` instead of `OnPropertyChanged("Variable")`, it still doesn't work :-(

Comment: Try the valueconverter approach, it IS the suggested way to convert one value to another, and still keep simple binding in the xAML.

Comment: I will try it, but it is bothersome to have a converter for every property I want to change.

Comment: It should be simpler - you only need converters where you are binding to a value, but want something else back, as in this example where you set your binding towards a bool, but want a solidColorBrush returned.

Answer (score 1):

Your property Model is automatic property i.e. it doesn't implement the getter or setter and OnPropertyChanged. Try changing Model property from

```
public ChangingVariable Model { get; set; }
```

to

```
private ChangingVariable model;
public ChangingVariable Model 
{ 
   get
   {
      return model;
   }
   set
   {
      model = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Model");
   }
```

The reason is that automatic properties don't notify the UI that they have changed.Even though the underlying property is changing. You have to basically call OnPropertyChanged method for Model as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Bad practice to name ChangingVariable the same as the type + you should use an underscore before.